# Login does not work on personal server

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to login an error of "Password is incorrect" is shown. But I know it's correct as it's on my server. Below is the registration form which interacts with the login mechanism on the server

Here is my code

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action=
        "%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E" id="form1">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login</strong></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="78">Username</td>

              <td width="6">:</td>

              <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id=
              "myusername" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Password</td>

              <td>:</td>

              <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>

              <td>&nbsp;</td>

              <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>

              <td>&nbsp;</td>

              <td>
              <?php include( 'config.php'); // makes sure they filled it in if (isset($_POST[ 'Submit'])){ $username=$ _POST[ 'myusername']; $password=$ _POST[ 'mypassword']; $md5_pw=m d5($password); if($username==" " || $password=="" ) { echo( 'You did not fill in a required field.'); } else{ $query=m ysql_query( "SELECT *FROM admin
                                  WHERE user_name = '$username'  ")or die(mysql_error()); $query2=m ysql_num_rows($query); if ($query2==0 ) { echo( "That user does not exist in our database. <a     href=signup.php>Click Here to Register</a>"); } while($result=m ysql_fetch_array( $query )){ if($md5_pw !=$ result[ 'password']) { echo ( "incorrect password"); } else { session_start(); header( "Location: home.php"); } } } } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me identify the error(s)?

Comment: Try to add `echo 'md5: '.$md5_pw;` and `echo 'password in database: '.$result['password'];` before `if($md5_pw != $result['password'])`, then see if both have the same value.

Comment: are you saving password as md5 format in database ?

Comment: Be sure you stores password in MD5 encryption in Database.
And also better to use the query like below  `$query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM admin WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password='$md5_pw' ")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @ekad Thank youvery much. I did it. Yes two passwords are different. Always 2 characters missing with password in database. It's because of password length in database. Now I increased it. Its work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you always get `Password is incorrect` message even though the entered password is correct and the code that produces the message is the following

```
if($md5_pw != $result['password'])
{
    echo ("incorrect password");
}
```

It's obvious that the value of `$md5_pw` and `$result['password']` are somehow different. You can check the values by adding `echo 'md5: '.$md5_pw;` and `echo 'password in database: '.$result['password'];` as follows

```
echo 'md5: '.$md5_pw;
echo 'password in database: '.$result['password'];

if($md5_pw != $result['password'])
{
    echo ("incorrect password");
}
```

Based on your comment, `$result['password']` is always two characters short, so the solution is changing the length of `password` column in the database.